# Microsoft Access - Between two date range with 1 user input

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want my query to ask the user for 1 date and use that same date to create a between date condition in my query. I manage to get the date to be used in the query, but I can't seem to be able to add +6 days to it.

Field

`dateRecorded`

Condition

`Between [Enter start date(mm/dd/yyyy)(Monday)] And [dateRecorded]+6`

I don't want the user to enter 2 dates to filter by.

Comment: It is nearly always better to use a small form, you get a lot more control.

Comment: Can you clarify "use a small form".

Comment: Create a form with the input you require. Reference the form in a query, or better, use parameters. For example, you could have a start and end date, easily updated in an after update event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter more than one parameter with the same request string it will only ask once and use the same input:

`Between [Enter an integer] And [Enter an integer]+6`

However I don't think this will work with dates; I know it does with integers etc.

I also agree with comments in question that it is better to use a form for such things to get more control; validation of correct dates such as ensuring the date entered is a Monday.

Comment: Consider: `Parameters [Enter Date] Date;
SELECT Table1.ADate
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.ADate) Between [enter date] And [enter date]+6));` This will work.